# Workflow base64 text -> iconv charset conversion -> modify text and backwards (OS X)

Tags: xml, base64, applescript, iconv

I am having the following situation:
I have XMLs, they contain entries which are base64 encoded. Decoding them doesn't seem a real problem (more on this later).
The decoded string is not UTF-8 but obviously USC2-Internal and can be converted using `iconv`.
Now I want to make changes and go back to XML replacing the node text entry with the converted data.

That's where the trouble starts (?).

Problem seems to be that the base64 decoding leaves a 5 byte set at the beginning which are not valid. So even the simple steps decode base64 to string, string to base64 doesn't work. I tried several methods using openssl, python etc. All those I found here as suggestions.
Anyway - the `iconv` command to convert does work.
But again changing back to USC-2-Internal will fail if not the "ugly bytes" are ignored.

Anybody here who can shed some light on these problems?
I can can post an example (just of the base64 string).

Thanks.

Here is the relevant part of the XML value:

```
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
```

For the script I used:

```
set convString to (do shell script "echo " & quoted form of convString & " | python -m base64 -d")
```

-->

```
Ê{"mTextParam":{"mAlignment":2,"mDefaultRun":[],"mHeight":124,"mHindiDigits":false,"mIndic":false,"mIsVerticalText":false,"mLeading":0,"mLigatures":false,"mRTL":false,"mShadowAngle":135,"mShadowBlur":0,"mShadowColor":0,"mShadowOffset":10,"mShadowOpacity":100,"mShadowVisible":false,"mStyleSheet":{"mBaselineShift":{"mParamValues":[[0,0]]},"mFillColor":{"mParamValues":[[0,16777215]]},"mFillOverStroke":{"mParamValues":[[0,true]]},"mFillVisible":{"mParamValues":[[0,true]]},"mFontName":{"mParamValues":[[0,"MinionPro-Regular"]]},"mFontSize":{"mParamValues":[[0,100]]},"mKerning":{"mParamValues":[[0,0]]},"mStrokeColor":{"mParamValues":[[0,16777215]]},"mStrokeVisible":{"mParamValues":[[0,false]]},"mStrokeWidth":{"mParamValues":[[0,1]]},"mText":"Some ˆzug¸l straﬂe.","mTracking":{"mParamValues":[[0,-24]]},"mTsumi":{"mParamValues":[[0,0]]}},"mTabWidth":400,"mWidth":1533},"mVersion":1}.
```

This string is a USC-2 flavour.
Making it readable especially the `mText` value I used `iconv` to open a backup of the string.

```
set convString to do shell script "echo | iconv -f UCS-2-INTERNAL -t utf-8 " & quoted form of buPath
```

-->

```
"ۦ{\"mTextParam\":{\"mAlignment\":2,\"mDefaultRun\":[],\"mHeight\":124,\"mHindiDigits\":false,\"mIndic\":false,\"mIsVerticalText\":false,\"mLeading\":0,\"mLigatures\":false,\"mRTL\":false,\"mShadowAngle\":135,\"mShadowBlur\":0,\"mShadowColor\":0,\"mShadowOffset\":10,\"mShadowOpacity\":100,\"mShadowVisible\":false,\"mStyleSheet\":{\"mBaselineShift\":{\"mParamValues\":[[0,0]]},\"mFillColor\":{\"mParamValues\":[[0,16777215]]},\"mFillOverStroke\":{\"mParamValues\":[[0,true]]},\"mFillVisible\":{\"mParamValues\":[[0,true]]},\"mFontName\":{\"mParamValues\":[[0,\"MinionPro-Regular\"]]},\"mFontSize\":{\"mParamValues\":[[0,100]]},\"mKerning\":{\"mParamValues\":[[0,0]]},\"mStrokeColor\":{\"mParamValues\":[[0,16777215]]},\"mStrokeVisible\":{\"mParamValues\":[[0,false]]},\"mStrokeWidth\":{\"mParamValues\":[[0,1]]},\"mText\":\"Some özugül straße.\",\"mTracking\":{\"mParamValues\":[[0,-24]]},\"mTsumi\":{\"mParamValues\":[[0,0]]}},\"mTabWidth\":400,\"mWidth\":1533},\"mVersion\":1}"
```

The problem is the way back.
As mentioned even the first decoded string can't be converted back to base64. For base64 compression I tried `openssl base64`.
It returns an error:

> sh: -c: line0: unexpected EOF while looking for matching

Hope this helps to make the problem a bit clearer (or the mistakes I'm doing).

---

The answer from yesterday has vanished ?! Fortunately I kept in mind the steps.

But just to extend the original question in regards of Murmel's correct note on JSON. I have no experience with JSON but from the readings about it I got the feeling that it is not too complicated.

Is there a recommended way (for my workflow) to convert a JSON  into a '.plist' XML and back. From the reading so far both will cover more or less the same data types - for my workflow (or problem).

An ideal workflow in case there is a way:

- get XML value
- decompress from base64
- convert to UTF
- convert JSON to PLIST
- connect the PLIST to user interface
- the user has readable text (any language) and can edit the text, font, font size and style
- convert PLIST to JSON
- convert JSON to USC2-Internal
- compress to base64
- replace XML value.

A simple text example:

> Arial **Bold**.

will change at least following JSON (PLIST) values:

> "mFontName":{"mParamValues":[[0,"ArialMT"],[7,"ArialMT-Bold"],[8,"ArialMT-Bold"],[9,"ArialMT-Bold"],[10,"ArialMT-Bold"]]}.
>
> "mText":"Arial Bold".

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd"><plist version="1.0"><dict><key>mFont</key><array><array><real>0</real><string>ArialMT</string></array><array><real>7</real><string>ArialMT-Bold</string></array><array><real>8</real><string>ArialMT-Bold</string></array><array><real>9</real><string>ArialMT-Bold</string></array><array><real>10</real><string>ArialMT-Bold</string></array></array><key>mText</key><string>Arial Bold</string></dict></plist>
```

If my edit doesn't make sense just disregard.

Comment: @Murmel, I've updated the question

Comment: 1. The whole XML-stuff is not relevant for your problem - right? (at best remove this part from your question) 2. You are provided with a JSON. This JSON uses USC-2-Internal as character encoding. The whole JSON is base64 encoded. 3. You want to modify the JSON. 4. Your first problem: Even base64 decoding the base64 encoded JSON and directly afterwards encoding it again does not work?

Comment: Regarding your actual problem: I could successfully execute: `echo -n "5gYA[...]AA==" | base64 -d | recode UCS-2-INTERNAL..utf-8 | recode utf-8..UCS-2-INTERNAL | base64`, can you execute these commands successfully too?

Comment: @Murmel,  I have not yet played with JSON. It doesn't seem to be too complicated. Thanks for the hint.

Comment: did you tried to execute [my proposed command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47000001/workflow-base64-text-iconv-charset-conversion-modify-text-and-backwards-o?noredirect=1#comment81037154_47000001)?

Comment: @Murmel. No. The suggested code doesn't work on standard OS X installation.